# PHP remove trailing zero based on variable number

Tags: php

I'd like to omit trailing zero from a number in PHP based on some options:

`decimals` = number of important decimal to return as a rule

`removeTrailingZero` = true / false: remove or not trailing zeros

`minDecimalsIfZero` = used when `removeTrailingZero` = true

Examples expected:

```
echo get_formatted_number(123.5670, array("decimals" => 2));
// returned: 123.57

echo get_formatted_number(123, array("decimals" => 2));
// returned: 123.00

echo get_formatted_number(123, array("decimals" => 8, "removeTrailingZero" => false));
// returned: 123.00000000

echo get_formatted_number(123, array("decimals" => 8, "removeTrailingZero" => true));
// returned: 123

echo get_formatted_number(123, array("decimals" => 8, "removeTrailingZero" => true, "minDecimalsIfZero" => 2));
// returned: 123.00

echo get_formatted_number(123.4657, array("decimals" => 8, "removeTrailingZero" => true, "minDecimalsIfZero" => 2));
// returned: 123.4657 <-- in this case i'd like to return this cause i've removed the trailing zero and number of decimals (4) is bigger than minDecimalsIfZero (2): ignore decimals option (8)

echo get_formatted_number(123.4657, array("decimals" => 8, "removeTrailingZero" => false, "minDecimalsIfZero" => 2));
// returned: 123.46570000 <-- in this case i'd like to return this cause removeTrailingZero is false
```

This is my actual function to modify.

```
function get_formatted_number($number, $options = array()) {

    if ( $number === "" ) {
        return "";
    }

    if ( $number === NULL ) {
        return "";
    }

    if ( isset($options['decimals']) ) {
        $decimals = (int)$options['decimals'] != "" ? (int)$options['decimals'] : 2;
    } else {
        $decimals = 2; //default = 2
    }

    $value = number_format($number, $decimals);

    return $value;
}
```

Comment: And your question is: ...

Comment: My question is how to check number of decimal part of a number to implement my checks? i've seen also str_pad to append values at the end (to trim based on my calculation) but i don't think is good for me cause str_pad want a defined lenght. But numbers like currency can be small or long. with not fixed lenght

Comment: Shouldn't `minDecimalsIfZero` be `maxDecimalsIfZero`? I don't understand the `get_formatted_number(123, array("decimals" => 8, "removeTrailingZero" => true, "minDecimalsIfZero" => 2));` one otherwise. Can you describe exactly what it's supposed to represent?

Comment: if I want to remove all zeros from a number, and minDecimalsIfZero is set, i want to retrieve the number with a minimum of zeros of decimal. so, 123 became 123.00000000 cause I set 8 decimal. then I remove all trailing zero cause option is true: i get: 123 but cause i want a minimum of digits in case of my number has not decimal, i want to return 123.00

Comment: So why does `echo get_formatted_number(123, array("decimals" => 8, "removeTrailingZero" => true))` return `123.00000000`? It's a typo, right?

Comment: Ops, yes is a typo sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this should do what you need. Refer to the comments:

```
function get_formatted_number($number, array $options = []): string
{
  // Default values
  static $DEFAULT_DECIMALS = 2;
  static $DEFAULT_REMOVE_TRAILING_ZEROS = false;
  static $DEFAULT_TRAILING_ZEROS_DECIMALS = 0;

  // Retrieve/sanitize options
  $decimals = array_key_exists('decimals', $options) 
    ? max($DEFAULT_DECIMALS, (int)$options['decimals']) 
    : $DEFAULT_DECIMALS;
  $remove_trailing_zeros = array_key_exists('removeTrailingZero', $options) 
    ? !!$options['removeTrailingZero'] 
    : $DEFAULT_REMOVE_TRAILING_ZEROS;
  $trailing_zeros_decimals = array_key_exists('minDecimalsIfZero', $options) 
    ? max($DEFAULT_TRAILING_ZEROS_DECIMALS, (int)$options['minDecimalsIfZero']) 
    : $DEFAULT_TRAILING_ZEROS_DECIMALS;

  // Set number of decimals from options
  $formatted_number = number_format($number, $decimals);

  // If option is set, remove trailing zeros, keeping an optional minimum
  if ($remove_trailing_zeros) {
    $formatted_number = (float)$formatted_number;
    if ($trailing_zeros_decimals >= strlen(substr(strrchr($formatted_number, '.'), 1))) {
      $formatted_number = number_format($formatted_number, $trailing_zeros_decimals);
    }
  }

  return $formatted_number;
}
```

**Demo here: https://3v4l.org/7eqBe**

Comment: Your code is more elegant than mine solution! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Found a possible solution:

```
function get_formatted_number($number, $options = array()) {

    if ( $number === "" ) {
        return "";
    }

    if ( $number === NULL ) {
        return "";
    }

    if ( isset($opzioni['removeTrailingZero']) ) {
        $removeTrailingZero= (bool)$opzioni['removeTrailingZero'];
    } else {
        $removeTrailingZero= false;
    }

    if ( isset($options['decimals']) ) {
        $decimals = (int)$options['decimals'] != "" ? (int)$options['decimals'] : 2;
    } else {
        $decimals = 2; //default = 2
    }

    if ( isset($opzioni['minDecimalsIfZero']) ) {
        $minDecimalsIfZero= $opzioni['minDecimalsIfZero'];
    } else {
        $minDecimalsIfZero = 2; //default
    }

    $value = number_format($number, $decimals);

    if ( $removeTrailingZero) {

        $value = preg_replace('/0{0,'.($decimals-$minDecimalsIfZero).'}$/', '', $value);

    } 

    return $value;
}
```